# shipping address is missing out on checkout

Tags: javascript, checkout, magento2

i don't know why but i get an error js on checkout.
When I'm on the payment step, The delivery address is absent:
[image]

when i look at with firebug, i I see an error js :

[image]

The error js which causes this malfunction is :

```
$parent.getCode is not a function.
```

I try to find where it came but can not resolve this error.
Would anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: We don't know why you get the error either.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but when you add 'simple products' in the admin without a weight, these products automatically become 'virtual products'. Virtual products do not require a shipping address, this might explain your issue?

Comment: no i found the issue !!the parameter "Display Billing Address On" must be on "payment method" and no "payment page"